# Calculando data e hora

Tags: c

Estou utilizando a estrutura tm do header time.h da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm dt_current, dt_begin;

    dt_current.tm_year = 2018;
    dt_current.tm_mon = 11;
    dt_current.tm_mday = 13;

    dt_current.tm_hour = 9;
    dt_current.tm_min = 45;
    dt_current.tm_sec = 0;

    printf("Data %d/%d/%d\n", dt_current.tm_mday, dt_current.tm_mon, dt_current.tm_year);
    printf("Hora %d:%d\n", dt_current.tm_hour, dt_current.tm_min);
    printf("-----------------\n");
    printf("10 dias atras\n");

    dt_begin = dt_current;
    dt_begin.tm_mday = dt_begin.tm_mday - 30;
    printf("Data %d/%d/%d\n", dt_begin.tm_mday, dt_begin.tm_mon, dt_begin.tm_year);
    printf("Hora %d:%d\n", dt_begin.tm_hour, dt_begin.tm_min);

    return 0;
}
```

Tem alguma função que eu possa retirar n dias da data (dt_current) ou preciso fazer o tratamento manualmente?

Comment: Tem que fazer manualmente. Só isso que queria saber?

Comment: Pensei em um jeito mais fácil, transformar datetime em dias e subtrair n dias, depois transformar novamente em datetime, tem alguma função que já faz isso ou na unha também?

Comment: Não existe tipo `datetime` tudo que ser na mão.

Answer (score 1):

Com a estrutura tm da lib time.h você pode atribuir data do sistema ou uma manualmente, o ponto é que uma vez que você faz alguma operação com sua data é necessário valida-la e isso é feito com o comando mktime.

```
struct tm dt_current;

dt_current.tm_year = 2018;
dt_current.tm_mon = 11;
dt_current.tm_mday = 13;
dt_current.tm_hour = 9;
dt_current.tm_min = 45;
dt_current.tm_sec = 0;

dt_current.tm_mday = dt_current.tm_mday - 30; // Voltar 30 dias

printf("%d/%d/%d\n", dt_current.tm_mday, dt_current.tm_mon, dt_current.tm_year);
// Saida: 17/11/2018 -> ESTA ERRADO

mktime(&dt_current); //Recalcular a data
printf("%d/%d/%d\n", dt_current.tm_mday, dt_current.tm_mon, dt_current.tm_year);
// Saida: 14/10/2018
```

O mesmo pode ser feito com as horas.